# understanding jtransform

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, fft

I want to do fft of an accelerometer data from android phone.I have chosen jtransform as fft library.Now I need some simple code to understand jtranform to write code to find fft from accelerometer data.
                                                                     Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the real data, you should pass these values to `realForward` function as stated [here](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/edu/emory/mathcs/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D.html#realForward%28double%5B%5D%29). When you pass the value array to this function it returns the results by overwriting this array with the FFT coefficients.

```
array = new double[arraySize];
...
DoubleFFT_1D dfft = new DoubleFFT_1D(arraySize);
dfft.realForward(array);
```

You should also consider the fact that output contains both real and imaginary parts:

if `arraySize` is even then

```
 array[2*k] = Re[k], 0 <= k < arraySize/2
 array[2*k+1] = Im[k], 0 < k < arraySize/2
 array[1] = Re[arraySize/2]
```

if `arraySize` is odd then

```
 array[2*k] = Re[k], 0 <= k < (arraySize+1)/2
 array[2*k+1] = Im[k], 0 < k < (arraySize-1)/2
 array[1] = Im[(arraySize-1)/2]
```